# jQuery select child element by class with unknown path

Tags: jquery, class, html, selector, css-selectors

I am trying to figure out the syntax for selecting a nth-child of an element by its class, however I don't know the exact path to the element. I can't do `$('parent > child > grandchild > hereIam');`

So basically I need to be able to say

```
$('#thisElement').AllRelativesWithClass('.classToSelect')
```

How exactly do I do that?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

According to this [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/find/), the find method will search down through the tree of elements until it finds the element in the selector parameters. So `$(parentSelector).find(childSelector)` is the fastest and most efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 48):

`$('#thisElement').find('.classToSelect')` will find any descendents of `#thisElement` with class `classToSelect`.

Comment: I prefer this answer because it shows dummy selectors with syntax, unlike the accepted one.

Answer (score 24):

This should do the trick:

```
$('#thisElement').find('.classToSelect')
```

Answer (score 12):

Try this

```
$('#thisElement .classToSelect').each(function(i){
         // do stuff
});
```

Hope it will help